# jQuery how to deal with rowspan in a table creation form

Tags: jquery, row, tabular

I have created a form that adds trs to a table. However the end result will be tricky because I have to somehow add and account for rowspan.

The "Dealership" & "Rank" td info can only be entered once, but you can add multiple dealers under that dealership. For each new dealer you create, I need to up the rowspan value for "Dealership" & "Rank"

Please see the image for a visual of what I need to achieve:

[image]

Here is the fiddle of the form:
http://jsfiddle.net/clintongreen/XYkcx/7/

Any pointers in the right direction will be greatly appreciated

Comment: What's to stop you from adding your new row and modifying the rowspan attribute of the <td>?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if this will work for you.
http://jsfiddle.net/XYkcx/10/
Basically I set up your function to run differently if it is the first time it's called.
If it's not the first time, the rowspan is being increased as you suggested.

Comment: OMG, thank you so much, I had no idea how I was going to accomplish this one. Cheers